# Rupee html symbol with font weight light

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

Is there any rupee font file with font weight light or any html symbols?

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="price"><span class="INR">Rs.</span> 40,000</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{font-family:'WebRupee';
       src:local('../fonts/web-rupee.eot');
       src:local('WebRupee'),
           url('../fonts/web-rupee.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('../fonts/web-rupee.woff') format('woff'),
           url('../fonts/web-rupee.svg') format('svg');
       font-weight:normal;
       font-style:normal}
.INR{font-family:'WebRupee';font-size:100%;font-weight:normal; margin-right:.2em}
.price{font: 100 40px Roboto;}
```

I want rupee font to be in light weight.

Thanks

Comment: use `font-weight: 100`

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: If your machine supports Unicode 6.0 its as easy as ₹ (&#x20B9;)
and another way:
<span style='font-weight:100;'>&#8377;</span>

Comment: for more detail:http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fZpXM/

Comment: still its not working :(

Comment: I am using the Roboto font with light weight and the font size is 40px. So the both font weight is not matching.

Comment: Why down vote? please consider adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine supports Unicode 6.0 its as easy as ₹ (`&#x20B9;`)
and another way:

```
<span style='font-weight:100;'>&#8377;</span>
```